# como puedo convertir fecha guardada en una tabla en minutos horas y segunods php

Tags: php

el caso es que no se me da muy bien trabajar con horas estoy crenado un sitio web en la cual los usuarios pueden publicar fotos so lo que yo quiero es que la hora que tengo almacenada en la tabla de mi base de datos en formato date time, a la hora de hacer una publicacion en vez de que aparesca esa fecha tan fea año mes dia hora etc.. que me aparesca mas o menos asi. hace 3 segundos , hace tantos minutos ,hace tantas horas . me doy a entender? gracias ojala y alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora? mira por favor el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente es algo bastante sencillo cuando lo analizas, te explico, lo que necesitas es obtener la fecha tal cual, así como la tienes almacenada en tu registro y después debes convertirla en formato unix

```
$fecha_de_la_tabla=strtotime("2018-05-04 12:00:00");
```

despues debes obtener la fecha actual y convertirla en formato unix

```
$unix_actual=time();
```

una vez que tengas esto debes restar el tiempo unix actual y el que tienes almacenado en tu tabla

```
$tiempo_transcurrido=$unix_actual-$fecha_de_la_tabla;
```

para finalizar debes utilizar esta funcion que te dejo para convertir el tiempo transcurrido en horas, minutos o segundos, segun sea el caso

```
function conversorSegundosHoras($tiempo_en_segundos) {
    $horas = floor($tiempo_en_segundos / 3600);
    $minutos = floor(($tiempo_en_segundos - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
    $segundos = $tiempo_en_segundos - ($horas * 3600) - ($minutos * 60);

    $hora_texto = "";
    if ($horas > 0 ) {
        $hora_texto .= $horas . "h ";
    }

    if ($minutos > 0 ) {
        $hora_texto .= $minutos . "m ";
    }

    if ($segundos > 0 ) {
        $hora_texto .= $segundos . "s";
    }

    return $hora_texto;
}

echo conversorSegundosHoras($tiempo_transcurrido);
```

Comment: gracias amigo ahora tengo una mejor comprencion de la logica para hacer lo que necesito lo probare y te cuento si me funciono 1000 gracias!!